# Takes 4 minutes to download profile image from facebook. What is the cause?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've spend about 4-5 hours on this an given up. Much research and tried many different solutions.

Basically I have a site using facebook SDK. All works fine on dev. Login and download user profile images via the facebook graph link.
However on live it takes around 4-5 mintues to download the profiles images. 
It's also slow to use facebook login.

I am using the following as a test with no other code.

```
<?php 

echo 'start<br />';
echo time( );
echo '<br />';
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/100007116990483/picture?type=large';
$file_location = '<my hidden root>/test1.jpg';

 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: ahm'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$fileName = $file_location;
$file = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
fputs($file, $result);
fclose($file);

echo 'end<br />';
echo time( );
echo '<br /><br />';
echo '<img src="http://www.aussiehousemates.com.au/test1.jpg" />';
?>
```

You can run this at
[www.aussiehousemates.com.au/fb-download-test.php](http://www.aussiehousemates.com.au/fb-download-test.php)

Also another test from a different server (Random image) is slow.
[www.aussiehousemates.com.au/fb-download-test2.php](http://www.aussiehousemates.com.au/fb-download-test2.php)

However this file uses the copy( ) function and the speed is what I expect.
Using copy for the other files results in a timeout.
[www.aussiehousemates.com.au/fb-download-test3.php](http://www.aussiehousemates.com.au/fb-download-test3.php)

What is this happening? WHat could be the cause?

The fast code is as follows

```
<?php 

echo 'start<br />';
echo time( );
echo '<br />';
$url = 'http://1dak.com/img/2012/06/beautiful-polish-girl-euro-2012.jpg';
$file_location = '/home/ahm/public_html/test.jpg';

copy($url, $file_location);

echo 'end<br />';
echo time( );
echo '<br /><br />';
echo '<img src="http://www.aussiehousemates.com.au/test.jpg" />';
?>
```

As stated above using copy( ) with the facebook image causes a timeout and nothing is returned.

Comment: Could you post your two approches - the fast one and the slow one? I assume, that on first link it's fast with fopen and on second it's slow with copy() ?

Comment: The code that is posted is the SLOW on. The SLOW one is using fopen. The fast one is using copy( ). I do not believe it is the code but something else. I will post the fast code using copy( ) above.